# angular track by and orderBy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

Starting to use Angular and playing with a demo. 
In the model, the event item includes a start time called starts_at and a title.

I had a tag using ng-repeat="event in events track by $index" and tried adding in "|orderBy: event.starts_at" It didn't seem to influence the sorting in any way until I removed the track section.

Does track disables any option for sorting in angular ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat filter expressions (and I suspect, order) come **before** tracking expressions.

Example:

```
item in items | filter:searchText track by item.id
```