# Angular items loading twice, but only sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

So I'm working a project where I load some dropdown panels (called "facets" in the project) based on templates using angular, and only on certain browser/hardware combinations, it loads the facets twice and deletes the second pair. Here's a video illustrating what's going on:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BywtASGJVCWmYXpSbE1zV3QxanM

(sorry about the format). What's interesting is that this is only occurring on the Chrome install in the video (that is, I have tested it with the same Chrome version installed on a different computer, and it didn't reproduce the error) and the IE 11 and Edge that are installed on my own computer. I added a `console.log("made a multiselect facet")` to the constructor for a certain type of facet (multiselect, obviously), and checked how many times it was printed. Here's a picture of Edge output on the left and Firefox Developer Edition on the right: [image: Edge vs Firefox Output]

So you can see that during the page load, the facets were created twice but only on Edge (because there's double the outputs). I've confirmed that the controller script isn't being run twice, with that "creating search criteria" bit, so it has to be occurring when the elements are actually added to the document (I think). Here's my template for the page I put the facets on (the relevant part anyway):

```
<md-card ng-repeat="facet in directory.criteria.Facets track by $index">
    <multi-Facet facet="facet"
        clear-action="directory.clearFilter(facet)"
        apply-action="directory.applyFilter(facet)"
        ng-if="directory.isMultiselectFacet(facet)"></multi-Facet>
    <ranged-Facet facet="facet"
        clear-action="directory.clearFilter(facet)"
        apply-action="directory.applyFilter(facet)"
        ng-if="directory.isRangeFacet(facet)"></ranged-Facet>
</md-card>
```

Because it's super long and I don't know if it'll be useful, I've included the controller as pastebin: http://pastebin.com/xNQUfZqs likewise with the actual template for a facet: http://pastebin.com/VcQHGp8L and its controller: http://pastebin.com/PHfNEEn4

A couple of notes: the controllers are all typescript, not javascript. Also, this is *NOT* related to issue #6006 on the angular.js github, because unless I'm very much mistaken this was fixed as of version 1.5.6 of angular, which is the one I have. Any other information is available on request.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your issue or not, but your html does have 1 issue that stands out for me. There are only a limited set of html elements that support self-closing tags (`/>`), and you can't add more. Using self-closing tags on an un-supported element (i.e. any directive) can cause the next sibling element to get completely ignored or render incorrectly.

Comment: Also... what are we supposed to be looking at in that video? Nothing stands out as odd to me...

Comment: If you look at about 00:12 at the sidebar panels you'll notice there are duplicates of them that are added beneath and swiftly removed. In the first page load, you don't see anything but I've confirmed via `console.log()`'s that the same error is occurring, it's just too fast to see.

Comment: Also, RE the self-closing tags, I changed them (see edit), but it didn't fix anything. Not that I really expected it to, it's just a good change to make, thanks for that.

Comment: It is better to use the clause `track by $index` in your `ng-repeat` statement. Can you check after adding that? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754386/angular-track-by-and-orderby since you are using `orderBy` also.

Comment: WHAT?!?!? that worked, Edge no longer loads twice. Can you write an answer explaining why that would be?

Comment: Update: my bad, this fixed the issue specifically in only one page, I've updated my question with a page that still experiences the issue when using `track by $index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use `track by $index` phrase in the end with `ng-repeat` like the following,

```
<md-card ng-repeat="facet in reqMan.criteria.Facets | orderBy:'DisplayOrder' track by $index">
```

Why does it prevent duplicates? As the official [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) say,

> To minimize creation of DOM elements, ngRepeat uses a function to "keep track" of all items in the collection and their corresponding DOM elements. For example, if an item is added to the collection, ngRepeat will know that all other items already have DOM elements, and will not re-render them.

I don't know what is the reason for duplicates here but `track by $index` prevents them.

You can use `track by $index` for every `ng-repeat` not just to prevent duplicates but also to improve the performance. Again referring to the docs,

> If you are working with objects that have an identifier property, you should track by the identifier instead of the whole object. Should you reload your data later, ngRepeat will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones. For large collections, this significantly improves rendering performance. If you don't have a unique identifier, track by $index can also provide a performance boost.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: An update to my update: Actually, this did work everywhere, I was just dealing with an edge case on one page where there was only one multifacet to load. See, the issue is that firefox was collapsing multiple identical statements from one script call and appending a number that showed how many times the message repeated which I didn't notice until now, whereas Edge just showed them all. So yes, this fully answers my question, thank you.